# PHP download file freezes the computer

Tags: php, download

I want to create a download link, and I found an example online. I forget where I get it.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
//$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$path = "music/";
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    //case "pdf":
    //header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
    //break;
    case "mp3":
    header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
    break;
    case "wma":
    header("Content-type: audio/wma"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
    break;
    case "ogg":
    header("Content-type: audio/ogg"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
    break;
    default:
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
}
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
}
fclose ($fd);
}
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```

The problem is when I click the download link, it works. But after few seconds, my whole computer freezes and I need to force a shutdown.

What is the cause of this problem? Is it my computer fault or the code? I am using WAMP Server 2.

Update :

I tried to use `readfile()` instead of `fread()`, however I still get the same problem. Below is my code :

```
<?php
$directory_load = simplexml_load_file('conf/configuration.xml');
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT'].$directory_load -> directories;
echo $path;
if($_GET['download_file'] != NULL) {
    $fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];
    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fullPath));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($fullPath);
        exit; 
    }
    else {
        echo "<span style=\"font-size: 15px;\">The file you requested to download <span style=\"font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: red; padding: 0px 20px;\">".$_GET['download_file']."</span> does not exists.</span>";
    }
}
else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

UPDATE 2 :

I tested the code with Mozilla version 21.0, it works fine. But as I stated, my computer freeze when I click the download link, it is when I am using Coolnovo (ChromePlus) Version 2.0.8.33. Is it related to the browser?

Comment: This code will keep reading the file till it reaches its end. If you're trying to use it with a large file, it'll probably eat a lot of system resources echoing back the file contents till you download the whole file

Comment: Hi @FilipposKarapetis, how can I fix it? Can I have an example? The code posted is copied from Internet example, and I am not good in `file processing`.

Comment: Filippos has a good point, what is the size of the file you're attempting to download?

Comment: @phpisuber01, the file size was about 2-4MB. I tried with the PDF, MP3, and other files, but I get the same result.

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis, I have updated my code, but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure your script is not getting timed out?

Comment: @AtulPundhir, what do you means by my script is not getting timed out?

Comment: Default time to execute script is by default 30 seconds.. so if it takes longer than your script will get timed out... you can see the setting in php.ini or by using php_info function

Comment: @AtulPundhir, I do this in `localhost`, I did not edit the maximum execution time, it is defaule, 30 seconds. I'm not upload it to live server before it's work fine in `localhost`.

Comment: I found that when I run the code with Coolnovo (ChromePlus), my computer will freeze. But when I tried with Mozilla, it's work perfectly. Is it related to browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try  clearing the buffer and flushing headers.  See example below:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $download_info->original . '"');
ob_clean();   // discard any data in the output buffer (if possible)
flush();      // flush headers (if possible)
readfile($path . $download_info->renamed);
```

[SureVerify - Email Verification](http://sureverify.com)

Comment: I think the major problem of my code is the file must be downloaded, if not the system will keep reading the file. Will the `readfile()` has the same problem with `fread`?

Comment: Will it related to browser? Because both the code work fine in Mozilla, but not Coolnovo (ChromePlus).